# How build search box like Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

Please how can make a search box that on click on the search icon should open another page for the search box Facebook search bar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is for asking specific programming questions. As it stands your question is far too broad. You need to come up with some sample code that demonstrates work that you have put in and what your exact problem is.

Comment: I tried to create a mini demo of your idea, using positioning ,hover, CSS grid etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create it using HTML and CSS only

## here the result:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.172);
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

nav input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 1.5em;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

nav input[type="text"]:hover,
nav input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: calc(90vw - 2em);
  color: rgb(0, 51, 255);
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  padding: 0 2em 0 0;
}

input[type="text"]:hover~svg,
input[type="text"]:focus~svg {
  right: 10px;
}

nav #content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  place-items: center;
}

#content svg {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="content">
      <input type="text">
      <!--search icon-->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 24 24" preserveaspectratio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope yt-icon"><g class="style-scope yt-icon"><path d="M20.87,20.17l-5.59-5.59C16.35,13.35,17,11.75,17,10c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7s-7,3.13-7,7s3.13,7,7,7c1.75,0,3.35-0.65,4.58-1.71 l5.59,5.59L20.87,20.17z M10,16c-3.31,0-6-2.69-6-6s2.69-6,6-6s6,2.69,6,6S13.31,16,10,16z" class="style-scope yt-icon"></path></g></svg>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```